# Integration question with square root

Tags: integration

$\int\sqrt {(1+3x^2+6x^3}dx$
I tried taking the substitution $u^2=1+3x^2+6x^3$. I was able to simplify the integral to $\frac{1}{(3x)(1+3x)} + \frac{x}{1+3x} + \frac{2x^2}{1+3x}$. I know I can form partial fractions of the first fraction and then integrate it but what about the second and third fractions? Is this the right approach? If yes, how do I proceed?

Comment: Assuming your computations are right, in the second and third fraction make the division.

Comment: I don't think you did it right. According to the Mathematica, answer is way longer and quite nasty.

Comment: I made a small algebraic error. I have edited the question

Comment: Doesn't matter. Here's what [WA](http://bit.ly/1DBofrc) says.

Comment: that doesn't help me

Comment: It'd more useful if you post how exactly you got that simplification. Looking at the WA answer, it seems to me that you got it wrong. Those simple and integrable fractions of yours cannot be reduced to the WA answer. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: this integral leads to an Elliptic one, it gives no antiderivative in the known elementary functions.